# reference a properties file from another one

Tags: java, file, properties

Is it possible to read a property in properties file from another propeties file? i need to make multiple properties files load their configuration from on main propeties file in a java project,
thanks for any help!

Comment: properties in java are handle with objects that open->read->close a file... you can use as many as you need, the question is: is that really a good idea?

Comment: Some components of the project rely on a specifically named properties file, some of their entries must be provided by the users, so instead of exposing all of these configuration files, one main file will be more convenient

Answer (score 1):

No but I suppose you can put the names of the other property files to load in a property of your main one and in your application load the corresponding files.

If you need things like macros, you can look at Jodd Props: http://jodd.org/doc/props.html